# VB.net: How to format money/numbers?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, formatting, currency

I do not know how to come up with the code to format an numbers.

```
Example:

Input into textbox : 1000
Result in textbox2: 1k

Example:

Input into textbox : 1000000
Result in textbox2: 1m

Example:

Input into textbox : 1000000000
Result in textbox2: 1b

Example:

Input into textbox : 2147483647
Result in textbox2: 2.147483647b
Example:

Input into textbox : 583967
Result in textbox2: 583.967k
```

How do I do that? Please help!!

Comment: Read and use [Custom Numeric Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx). Try to play with group separator

Comment: @Fabio, that's not going to work because the requested format is nothing that .NET numeric formatting handles.

Comment: There is nothing built into VB that will do this for you.  You're going to have to use some maths and logic.  You would do it exactly as you would if you were using a pen and paper.  You'd start by dividing by 1000 and then testing whether the remainder is 1000 or more.  If it's not then you you output the number with the "k" suffix.  If it is then you divide again and so on.  Pick up a pen and paper and write out the steps you need to perform to do it manually and then write code to implement those steps.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, it is possible with `Custom Numeric Format`, that is why i add _Try to play with..._. `String.Format("{0:0,.###'k'}", yournumber)`. Of course he need to use own method to decide how much scaling groups to be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with conditional arithmetic grouping

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim Input As ULong
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ")
        Input = Convert.ToUInt64(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(Input))
    End Sub

    Public Function FormatNumber(ByVal Input As ULong) As String
        Dim Result As String = Input.ToString()

        If Input >= 1000000000
            Result = String.Format("{0}b", Input / 1000000000) 
        Else If Input >= 1000000
            Result = String.Format("{0}m", Input / 1000000)
        Else If Input > 1000
            Result = String.Format("{0}k", Input / 1000)
        End If

        Return Result
    End Function
End Module
```

Results:

```
Enter a number: 123000000000
123b
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E6HWvT)

Comment: Hi shar1er80, this was what i was looking for, but is there a way to make the maximum integer higher? Like 10b but not stop at 2147483647? Thanks!

Comment: @pleasega Depends on how high you want to go, but I've updated my answer to support a number as high as 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  How ever you'll have to add more if conditions if you want to have a format that supports trillion, quadrillion, and quintillion.

Answer (score 1):

.NET have not a literal constant for the number group.
But you can use number scaling of [Custom Numeric Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.80).aspx) and add your character to the custom format

```
Private Function GetMyFormat(value As Int64) As String
    Select Case Math.Abs(value)
        Case Is < 1000000
            Return "0,.############'k'"
        Case Is < 1000000000
            Return "0,,.############'m'"
        Case Else
            Return "0,,,.############'b'"
    End Select
End Function
```

Then use it with `.ToString` method

```
Dim number As Int64 = 109106
Dim format As String = Me.GetMyFormat(number)
Me.TextBox2.Text = number.ToString(format)
```

Or create extension method

```
<Extension>
Public Function ToStringWithMyFormat(this As Int64)
    Dim format As String = "0,,,.############'b'"
    Select Case Math.Abs(this)
        Case Is < 1000000
            format = "0,.############'k'"
        Case Is < 1000000000
            format = "0,,.############'m'"
    End Select        
    return this.ToString(format)
End Function
```

And use it:

```
Dim number As Int64 = 109106
Me.TextBox2.Text = number.ToStringWithMyFormat()
```